Loading shapes from the DB in excalidraw is triggering on chnage
im building a real time collaborative platform the frontend is in next js with excalidraw and backend is in flask and mongo db, for the data-base, the broadcasting the shapes to other folks works well but the problem arises when i store the created shapes in the db, and load the shapes using the /retrieveCanvasState endpoint now this endpoint returns all the previously created shapes AND THE PROBLEM ARISES be it either using .updateScene or even with update the state directly doing either of the 2 is triggering the on change repeatedly hence calling the backend again and sending the data of the same shapes to the  backend again
code ->
const Board = () => {

  const [excalidrawAPIState, setexcalidrawAPIState] = useState(null);
  const [hasPrevousElements, setHasPreviousElements] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!router.isReady || !excalidrawAPIState) return
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('board_uuid', router.query.BoardUuid)
      try {
        const canvasState = await axios.post(`${backendDomainHandler()}/retrieveCanvasState`, formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        })
        // console.log(canvasState.data);
        if (canvasState.data.data?.length > 0) {
          setHasPreviousElements(true)// -> note this flagg also does not work
          console.log('api call fn', canvasState.data.data);
          excalidrawAPIState.updateScene({ elements: canvasState.data.data })
          // setElementsState({ elements: canvasState.data.data })
        }
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })()
  }, [router.isReady, excalidrawAPIState])



 const versionsMap = useRef(new Map()).current;
  const [elementsState, setElementsState] = useState({
    elements: [],
  });



  const canvasOnChangeHandler = debounce((allElements, setElementsState, versionsMap, callToBackendToUpdateCanvasState) => {
    const newIds = new Set(allElements.map(el => el.id));
    const elementsChanged = new Set();

    // Check for updates or new additions
    allElements.forEach(element => {
      const storedVersion = versionsMap.get(element.id) || 0;
      if (!versionsMap.has(element.id)) {
        console.log('Add event', element);
        callToBackendToUpdateCanvasState("addShape", element);
        elementsChanged.add(element.id);
      } else if (element.version > storedVersion && !element.isDeleted) {
        console.log(element.isDeleted, 'is deleted');
        console.log('Update event', element);
        callToBackendToUpdateCanvasState("updateShape", element);
        elementsChanged.add(element.id);
      } else if (element.version > storedVersion && element.isDeleted) {
        console.log('Delete event', element.id);
        callToBackendToUpdateCanvasState("deleteShape", { id: element.id });
        versionsMap.delete(element.id);
        elementsChanged.add(element.id);
      }

      versionsMap.set(element.id, element.version);
    });

   
    if (elementsChanged.size > 0) {
      setElementsState({ elements: allElements });
    }
  }, 1100);

  const handleChange = (elements, appState) => {
    console.log('on change trugger');
    if (hasPrevousElements) return
    canvasOnChangeHandler(elements, setElementsState, versionsMap, callToBackendToUpdateCanvasState);
  };

return (
          <Excalidraw excalidrawAPI={(e) => setexcalidrawAPIState(e)} onChange={handleChange} initialData={elementsState} />

)


}

export default Board

can somebody please help me with this 
